# Two versions of the same libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, openssl

I've been given a project previously mantained by another person and I had to install OpenSSL to be able to do various things.
OpenSSL has been installed via CocoaPods and it works just fine. The problem is that the project had another library called "Cipher" that it was using to encrypt some info using a 509x certificate.
I haven't touched that part of the code, but it now doesn't work anymore.
This library contains 4 files: libcrypto.a, libssl.a, oaep.c and oaep.h.
The OpenSSL library linked via CocoaPods also contains libcrypto.a and libssl.a.

This is the code that now doesn't work anymore:

```
- (NSMutableString *)cipherWithBlock: (NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString *cipherBlock = [NSMutableString string];
    static NSString* stringBlock = kLIT_EMPTY;
    stringBlock = string;
    NSData *crt = [[IWUserController sharedInstance] publicKey];
    unsigned char block [DIGEST_BUFFER_SIZE];
    const char* msg = [stringBlock cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    cipher((void*)[crt bytes], crt.length, msg, block);
    for (int i = 0; i < DIGEST_BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        [cipherBlock appendFormat:@"%02X", block[i], nil];
    return cipherBlock;
}
```

This method actually produces an encripted string, but the web service that is receiving it says that it's not valid.
I have no idea what to do. the only thing I know is that the old version with the same exact code, but without OpenSSL, works just fine.
Any idea?

Comment: Ok as I'm getting more info, I want to update my question too. it turns out that I now have lots of warnings in Xcode saying that all the files in those two libraries (the ones in the Pods) were built for newer iOS version (9.2) than being linked (7.0).
As these warnings came from the class that I did not touch, I now think that this class is importing the new library rather than the old working one.
Is there any way to import a different version of the library just in this class?

Comment: I've finally solved the problem but in a very "dirty" way: I've copied the old libraries over the new ones in the pod. The problem now is that the digital sign that I was making with the new libraries doesn't work anymore. Seems to me that the old libraries were compiled at 32 bits, while the new ones are compiled at 64bits. I'm now seeing lots of warnings about losing integer precision, could it be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to use a forked version of the OpenSSL framework in which the libraries libcrypto.a and libssl.a have been downgraded to the same, modified ones, that the proyect originary used.
This way the old encrypting methods and the new ones I've added are working.